# Help identifying SMD components with cryptic code

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I've tried various SMD codebooks but the marking is so vague. The components I'm looking for is the 6-pin (SOT-363?) components with code "12" and vertical "L". I guess that  all those vertically positioned markings (46, L, B6) are irrelevant (another board I have has this component with vertical "N" and not "L") thus the code would just be "12". Perhaps those two dots will be of any help to narrow down the possibilities -- do they indicate two ground pins by any chance?

I've found that one of the possible components could be MUN5312DW1T1, but those two dots keep me from pinpointing it as this components usually (always?) has one dot.

[image]

Comment: If you had a DMM, you could scrape off the silkscreen on the vias (carefully) and see which ones are conductive to ground.

Comment: Trace the surrounding circuit. If you hade an idea of what function they perform it would narrow down the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty similar to a [Leshan Radio](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Digital-Transistors_LRC-LMUN5312DW1T1G_C2936684.html) version of the Onsemi part (look at the photo and datasheet).

[image]

The sideways character is typically something like a lot or date code so not very relevant to the part number.